# What kind of objects does Dir.foreach yield up? They're returning weird sizes

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to iterate over each file in a directory, and output its filename and filesize.

To do this, I am saying

```
Dir.foreach(files) do |f|
    puts f.size
end
```

For each file in the directory 'files', print its filesize to the screen.

Problem is, this is yielding up weird values -- always integers under 60, when I know there are 400-500 MB files in the folder. So I read the Ruby documentation, and it doesn't actually tell me what kind of object `f` becomes within the block. It doesn't seem to be a `File` object, the type of thing you'd get with `File.open("file.mpg","r")`, because if I open one of the individual files using that method and then print its size with `.size`, I get back its filesize in bytes just as I'd expcet.

So what *is* `f`, and how can I report on filesizes properly?

Comment: Really? The documentation for [foreach](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Dir.html#method-c-foreach) is pretty clear about it: `Calls the block once for each entry in the named directory, passing the filename of each entry as a parameter to the block.` A `filename` is a String. It's not a File or IO object.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way :

```
Dir.foreach(files) do |f|
    puts File.size(f) if File.file?(f)
end
```

`f` is a file name but it is a *string*. Look this [`File::size`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/File.html#method-c-size) to get the file's *size*.

Answer (score 1):

The Ruby [`Dir.foreach(...)` docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Dir.html#method-c-foreach) say:

> ... passing the *filename* of each entry as a parameter to the block.

Filenames are strings.  As such, `size` returns the [length of the filename string](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-size).

Consider using [`File.stat(filename).size`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File/Stat.html#method-i-size) which will return the size of the named file (and you don't have to remember to "close" it like you would a plain `File`).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're starting with the wrong class. You're assuming Dir will return objects of some derivative class. Instead, use Ruby's [Pathname](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) class:

```
require 'pathname'

Pathname.new(ENV['HOME']).children.each do |pname|
  puts pname.to_s
  puts pname.size
end
# >> /home/tinman/applications
# >> 102
# >> /home/tinman/bin
# >> 1020
# >> /home/tinman/development
# >> 1054
# >> /home/tinman/documents
# >> 884
# >> /home/tinman/downloads
# >> 612
# >> /home/tinman/src
# >> 136
# >> /home/tinman/tmp
# >> 102
# >> /home/tinman/vim
# >> 612
```

The values of `pname` in the block are Pathname objects:

```
Pathname.new(ENV['HOME']).children.first.class # => Pathname
```

The "sizes" for the above are actually not bytes, they're the size of the directory allocation, because they're actually directories being listed.

If I look at a directory containing a file I can see the size of the file in bytes:

```
require 'pathname'

Pathname.new(ENV['HOME']).join('tmp').children.each do |pname|
  puts pname.to_s
  puts pname.size
end

# >> /home/tinman/tmp/binary_search_file~
# >> 1812
```

In other words, you have to be aware of what you're looking at; Just because it's on disk doesn't mean the value `size` returns will actually mean the number of bytes in the object.

See [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) for more information.